# jQuery .text borra el texto

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy usando mi codigo para setear el valor de un `<p>` a el texto escrito en un `<input>` de tipo texto, de esta manera:

```js
var textoNuevo = $("#comment-input").val();

$("#upload-comment").click(function() {
    $(".my-new-comment-comment").text(textoNuevo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="comment-input" type="text">

<button type="submit" id="upload-comment" name="submit">
  enviar
</button>

<p id="comment" class="my-new-comment-comment">texto de prueba</p>
```

Como pueden ver, si escribes algo en la input y das en enviar, el texto de prueba desaparece, pero lo que quiero hacer es que se cambie a lo que escribiste en la input.

Como puedo hacer esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en que antes del evento `click` ya estas tomando el valor de la variable, osea un valor vacio, entonces cuando haces `click` no te toma el valor actual, sino el anterior, la solucion es simple, agrega `textoNuevo` dentro de tu funcion, asi:

```js
$("#upload-comment").click(function() {
  var textoNuevo = $("#comment-input").val();
    $(".my-new-comment-comment").text(textoNuevo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="comment-input" type="text">

<button type="submit" id="upload-comment" name="submit">
  enviar
</button>

<p id="comment" class="my-new-comment-comment">texto de prueba</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

El error es simple, estás asignando el valor fuera del upload.
Por lo que nunca toma el nuevo valor agregado.
Solo debes mover el un poco el javascript, de este modo:

```js
$("#upload-comment").click(function() {
    var textoNuevo = $("#comment-input").val();
    $(".my-new-comment-comment").text(textoNuevo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="comment-input" type="text">

<button type="submit" id="upload-comment" name="submit">
  enviar
</button>

<p id="comment" class="my-new-comment-comment">texto de prueba</p>
```